# associated data in linq select

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

I need to select data from different tables associated, I have a hospital table, another specialty, and other services, and what is held to select all hospitals and their specialties and services, there is a way to do this in linq?

this is what I'm trying

```
var hospitalesQuery = from hospital in App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.Hospitales
                                          where hospital.id_tipo == "2" && hospital.christus == "1"
                                          orderby hospital.distancia ascending
                                          from e in App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.EspHosp
                                          where e.fk_hospital==hospital.pk_hospital
                                          from s in App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.ServHosp
                                          where s.fk_hospital==hospital.pk_hospital
                                          select new Hospitale()
                                {
                                    pk_hospital = hospital.pk_hospital,
                                    nombre = hospital.nombre,
                                    direccion = hospital.direccion,
                                    ciudad = hospital.ciudad,
                                    id_ciudad = hospital.id_ciudad,
                                    estado = hospital.estado,
                                    id_estado = hospital.id_estado,
                                    id_tipo = hospital.id_tipo,
                                    tipo_descripcion = hospital.tipo_descripcion,
                                    imagen = hospital.imagen,
                                    gps_lat = hospital.gps_lat,
                                    gps_lng = hospital.gps_lng,
                                    abierto_lv = hospital.abierto_lv,
                                    abierto_sd = hospital.abierto_sd,
                                    telefono_1 = hospital.telefono_1,
                                    telefono_2 = hospital.telefono_2,
                                    telefono_3 = hospital.telefono_3,
                                    telefono_4 = hospital.telefono_4,
                                    telefono_5 = hospital.telefono_5,
                                    inactivo = hospital.inactivo,
                                    christus = hospital.christus,
                                    especialidades= new List<Especialidade>(e),
                                    servicios= new List<Servicio>(s)
                                };
```

Comment: Try to join the objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: What database/ORM are you using? LINQ is a query language, not the ORM itself. It's far easier to create a mapping between the entities in your ORM's configuration than "joining" objects after the fact

Comment: it is a sdf database for local storage on wp8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for joining tables by a foreign key. LINQ (asn SQL as well) provide `join` for this:

```
from hospital in App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.Hospitales
where hospital.id_tipo == "2" && hospital.christus == "1"
join e in App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.EspHosp on hospital.pk_hospital equals e.fk_hospital
join s in App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.ServHosp on hospital.pk_hospital on s.fk_hospital
orderby hospital.distancia ascending
select new Hospitale()
{...
```

**Update.** If you want to load list dependencies for each of the hospitals, I do not think you can do this with one query in EF. This is as close as you can get:

```
var hospitals = (from hospital in App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.Hospitales
    where hospital.id_tipo == "2" && hospital.christus == "1"
    orderby hospital.distancia ascending
    select new Hospitale()
    {
        pk_hospital = hospital.pk_hospital,
        ...
    }).ToList();

foreach (var h in hospitals)
{
    h.especialidades = App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.EspHosp.Where(e => e.fk_hospital==h.pk_hospital).ToList();
    h.servicios = App.ViewModel.ChristusDB.ServHosp.Where(e => s.fk_hospital==h.pk_hospital).ToList();
}
```

However this would be a lot of queries to the DB, which might perform poorly. You should really think about redesigning your EF data model properly so that the framework does this job of loading dependencies for you.

Comment: yes but the trouble is that i need a list with the result from the joining,and i don't know how to get this, at the 'especialidades' and 'servicios' columns

Comment: @ErickGarciaV I assume that the query always runs from the same location (hospital.distancia)?  Andrei's answer is correct from what I can tell.  If you want to pull the records just do `var results = hospitalesQuery.ToList()`;

Comment: no, i'm sorry, that's not what i'm looking for, i had code it that answer, and its only giving me one result, in a while i'll put the best approach that i can get.

Comment: @ErickGarciaV, think I understood what you are after. Please see update

Comment: yep thats is the same answer that i was about to put, :( its a shame that there is no way to get to that with linq,regrettably it is the best design of the data model,and this is due to the relationship, thanks i will mark your answer as good :)